# Performance testing Dynamics CRM using JMeter tool

Tags: jmeter, dynamics-crm, performance-testing, jmeter-5.0

I have recently started using JMeter and I'm still trying to get to grips with it. I am trying to use JMeter to performance test Dynamics CRM. I have created a test plan and included a thread group with the HTTP authorization manager. I have added an HTTP Request and set the path to the 'homepage'. This appears to be working, but when I try some other requests I am getting the following response body :

'Important: Microsoft Dynamics CRM makes extensive use of your Web browser's client-side abilities. You either have one of these features turned off or your security settings are set so high that they prevent these features from being used. To enable these features, change your browser settings to allow the Microsoft Dynamics CRM site to run JavaScript. '

My question is how can I configure JMeter to avoid this error? As far as I understand, JMeter it does not make use of a browser unless you're recording a test script so I'm unsure how I can change settings.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Dynamics uses a lot of browser-side JavaScript. JMeter has a [plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverTutorial/) which can execute this JavaScript.

However...you will need to be fairly sophisticated in what you measure. The performance of the JavaScript will depend on your test hardware, and won't represent what "normal" users see - you're testing the performance of JavaScript in a browser, rather than the Dynamics server.

An alternative would be to look at the calls the JavaScript makes to server-side resources, and capture those as JMeter calls. This does mean reverse-engineering the application logic to understand how the Dynamics client-side application interacts with the server.